# Putting multiple subsections in a row

Tags: titlesec

I'm answering some preset questions for a report and in some cases, it's more logical to answer a couple questions together for the sake of consistancy.

Is it possible to get multiple subsections numbers on a single line (there's no title, only the numbers) ?
I've tried putting them in a tabular, which somewhat works, but indents them slightly and space them out too much.

here's what I've got for now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\subsection{}
    \subsection{}
    \subsection
    %with or without protect doesn't work
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \subsection{}&\subsection{}&\subsection{} 
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks ! first-time asker but i've been looking around the website for a while. Pretty surprised no one actually asked this before too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of setting the subsection numbers of `\subsection` can be simulated, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\newsubsectionnumber}{%
  \refstepcounter{subsection}%
  \textbf{\large\thesubsection}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\subsection{}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
  \newsubsectionnumber &
  \newsubsectionnumber &
  \newsubsectionnumber \\
\end{tabular}
\subsection{}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Will this continue the numbering for following subsection ?

Comment: @RomainB. Yes, see updated answer.